# Celery task complete django notification

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I'm starting with celery for a module in django which will import large csvs.
The user will give the file and the some other fields and the csv will be checked and then sent to celery.
Now what should i do for the notification?
I want the user to be able to leave the page but get some kind of notification when the tasks complete.
I am planning to put all the rows in a group and use a chord to callback some django view or url to send a popup notification to the user about the completion of the taks.
In this way i'm trying to avoid polling.

Would this work and would this be the right way about going?

Comment: Can't you create some kind of notification model when finishing the celery task?

Comment: please elaborate, i'm not so experinced with django either, do you mean a django model when you say notification model?